# Android : admob on canvas

Tags: java, android, admob, android-canvas

How to draw working example of AdMob on Canvas ? I searched all web but didn't find really working answer ! please help !

Answer (score 0):

AdMob's AdView is a plain old view, which may not play well with Canvas. In these cases, AdMob recommends putting the AdView outside of the Canvas or a SurfaceView as a sibling element.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the canvas size as whole screen size - adview size. Then add the adview to a relative layout along with the canvas view. it will work